# How can I make <img> not affect div height

Tags: html, css

I want to make image inside this div container not to affect its container size when stretching, I'd like it to go outside up and bottom if that's possible without setting container height or by assigning negative top or bottom with position.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: skyblue;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top:50px;
}

img {
  position:relative;
  width: 500px;
  top:-30px;
}

.column1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.column2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">Hello world</div>
  <div class="column2">
    <img src="https://food.fnr.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2013/6/28/0/FNK_Apple-Pie_s4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.826.620.suffix/1382545039107.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically what i want is for image to not affect container size, when stretching image size of the div to stays the same while it can go outside but without setting height for the div like this.

EDIT: I want to make image not affect it's div size ( that i can do with the height ) but i also want it to overlay not only from the bottom but also from the top of the div ( like it is now but without using negative top position in the css )

Comment: but the container `div` will stretch to fit the `img`unless you specify a `height` for it.

Comment: right, is there any other way using flexbox? To make it more responsive, also how can i make it overlay div from the up, not only bottom without using some negative positions?

Comment: so, you want the final height of the container `div` to be only the `height` of `.column1` text and the `img` to be at the bottom ?

Comment: let me edit this snippet to show you what i actually want but not with that approach ( since it's wrong )

Comment: yeah that would be great.

Comment: ok so now it is edited :)

Comment: unfortunately, the edit didn't help that much.

Comment: hmmm, what concerns you? :)

Comment: in a comment, try to briefly describe the intended result.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set `position: absolute;` on the image to bring it outside of the document flow which will have the effect you desire.

If you are not using flexbox another option will be to set `float` which will bring the image outside of the document flow as well.

A third option will be to set `height` to `column2` to make it not care about children heights. But that's kind of a hack and I can't confirm it will work on all possible browsers.

```
.column2 {
  height: 1px;
}
```

Also please keep in mind that by doing this the image will start to overlap elements that are below your container div.

Comment: Yeah but when resizing and trying to make it responsive, position:absolute is doing it wrong :/

Comment: hm ok, so you want to keep the image in the document flow, but also to make it not affect the background?

Comment: so umm i can do this with absolute position and make a query that when under 900px absolute does not exist. is it good approach?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice and cool way to make a background image work like an img element so it adjust its height automatically. You need to know the image width and height ratio. Set the height of the container to 0 and set the padding-top as percentage based upon the image ratio.

It will look like the following:

```css
div {
  background-image: url('http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100 % ;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 66.64 % ; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
  /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
```